# How to disable/enable office clipboard

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, office365, microsoft-office-2016

**Question:** Is there any way that you can disable clipboard in Office 2016?

I don't mean show/hide status when coping or similar stuff from clipboard options. I mean to completely turn it off. It so intrusive that you cant turn it off from the application itself. Also it's a privacy concern because everything that you copy on your device goes there if any application (Excel, Word, etc.) is open. If they are all closed it will copy system clipboard to Office clipboard when you start Word/Excel.

I'm looking for any kind of solution (3rd party, registry, etc...). I have Win 7/64 bit and Office 2016/64 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a registry key we were provided by Microsoft to disable Office's clipboard. It's HKCU, so not as easily deployable, but seems to be functioning for our needs.  More testing is ongoing.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2817672/macro-takes-longer-than-expected-to-execute-many-individual-copy-and-p

> To resolve this issue in Excel for Office 365, Excel 2019, Excel 2016 and Excel 2013, follow the steps in the "Registry key information" section.
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type regedit in the **Open** box, and then click
>      **OK**.
> 2. Locate and then select the following registry subkey:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Common\General\
>    ```
>
>    **Note xx.0** in this registry path corresponds to the Excel version (16.0 = Excel 2016, 15.0 = Excel 2013, 14.0 = Excel 2010).
> 3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **DWORD Value**.
> 4. Type AcbControl, and then press Enter.
> 5. In the **Details** pane, right-click **AcbControl**, and then click **Modify**.
> 6. In the **Value data** box, type either decimal **2147483648** or hexadecimal **80000000**, and then click **OK**.
> 7. Exit Registry Editor.

Comment: Still works for MSO 2019; needs a complete restart of all MSO applications. On a related note, one can also use `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Clipboard` for changing a similar **Windows 10 Clipboard** settings.

Comment: To add an update: Had to disable for O365 and wondered what the xx numbers should be. Found that MSO 2016, 2019 and 365 all use 16.0 regex path. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word

Answer (score 1):

### Disabling the Clipboard

Below is a workaround method to disable the clipboard functionality using a ***batch script*** with some conditional logic and a loop. There's also a method and some instructions below that outlining how to easily kill the loop. It uses some dynamic VB scripting language to help keep the process hidden in the background while running but it  still gives you the control to use it and kill it as needed.

### Batch Script

```
IF /I [%~N1]==[KillSwitch] TASKKILL /F /FI "WindowTitle eq ClearClip" & EXIT
IF NOT DEFINED MINIMIZED SET MINIMIZED=1 && START "" /MIN "%~F0" x && EXIT
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT [%~1]==[] GOTO :VBProcess

TITLE ClearClip
:LoopIt
ping -n 02 127.0.0.1 > nul

:WipeClip
cmd.exe /c echo off | clip
GOTO :LoopIt

:VBProcess
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpVBSTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"

ECHO Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) ^& "%~F0" ^& Chr(34), 0 >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WinScriptHost = Nothing                       >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
EXIT
```

> **Essentially this. . .**
>
> - Kills all processes with a title of "`ClearClip`" if the "`KillSwitch`" named file is passed to it as the first argument and
>     then exits the script entirely (see **Killing it with the Kill
>     Switch**)
> - Starts [itself] the batch script again but minimized and with a passed dummy "`x`" value first argument
> - Starts [itself] the batch script hidden with a dynamic VB script if the first argument passed to it is not null and then loops every 2
>     seconds clearing the clipboard

### To use it

To use it or turn on the functionality to clear out the clipboard every 2 seconds, simply double-click or execute the batch script. If you have trouble or it does not work as expected, try running it elevated as administrator with a simple ***right-click | Run as administrator***.

---

### Killing it with the Kill Switch

1. Create a file with the name of `KillSwitch.txt` and place it right next to the batch script you saved that you execute to disable the clipboard
2. Drag and drop the `KillSwitch.txt` name file right into or onto the batch script that you execute to disable the clipboard, and this will kill the hidden background processes that clears the clipboard and then clipboard will be available again.

   [image]

   [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [Goto](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Title](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html)
- [.Run](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html)
- [CScript](https://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)
- `CALL /?`

  > ```
  > Substitution of batch parameters (%n) has been enhanced.  You can
  > now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  >     %~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
  >     %~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
  >     %~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
  > ```
- [Automatically clear your clipboard with ClipTTL](https://betanews.com/2016/10/31/automatically-clear-your-clipboard-with-clipttl/)

Comment: @IGRACH This solution will allow someone to consciously turn off the clipboard functionality just before launching the concerning Office application(s) as well as turn it back on too. Otherwise you could automate and further expand and automate turning this on or off if processes such as `winword.exe`, `excel.exe`, etc. are found or not found running in memory on the machine you automate it to run. You literally said "any kind of solution" and thus this solution is what I'm providing you with to see if it will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, but I'm actually looking to disable clipboard all together, not just to purge it.

Comment: @IGRACH No worries but this is a workaround solution I came up with upon research and testing. I found posts about disabling clipboard history, experience, and some other features of clipboard but nothing to actually disable it even GPO but perhaps there is something you will find that someone else knows about. In the meantime, this solution essentially prevents that functionality from being used so give it a try and you may determine that it will suffice in the interim, but nonetheless, good luck finding something more direct or specific for the disabling of that feature entirely.